# Windows Search service doesn't work Windows 10

Tags: windows, search

I have an error when I'm trying to start Windows Search service. My search in the start menu doesn't work without this service.

[image: Error 87: The parameter is incorrect]

Comment: Have you used the SFC and DISM tools to repair your installation?  Are you connected to a domain?  Did you at any point attempt to disable Cortana?

Comment: What does it mean: SFC and DISM? I tried to use default windows troubleshot fixer, but it can't help me.
Cortana is not available for my country, and in task list I haven't Cortana process.

Comment: Yes, i connected to corporate domain

Comment: Do some research on how to run SFC and DISM to verify the integrity of your system installation.  Verify the Service isn't being disable by a group policy.

Comment: I tried to use SFC and it help me!
After using "sfc /scan now" and reboot, everything stays ok. 
You can post it as an answer and I will take you the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuild your index...

`Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced -> Rebuild`

and I also suggest to move your database to another drive as the database tends to grow fast...

`Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced -> Index Location`

Comment: Rebuild didn't help. Index location field is non-active

Comment: If you are in a corporate Environment you should ask your local Administrator. Maybe re-installing the Feature will help

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Windows Search:

```
dism /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:"SearchEngine-Client-Package"
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"SearchEngine-Client-Package"
```